# Display JSON data to HTML page using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

First time being exposed to JSON so please explain like I'm 5 without the jargon.
I have been given a JSON file like this and need to display these items in a list in HTML.
A lot of examples have the JSON object assigned to a variable- this isn't assigned to a variable so I'm unsure how to reference it.
How can I access and display everything in product list.
In my html I have linked to a script.js file and also this json file.

HTML

```
  <h1>My Cart</h1>
    <div id="cart">
        <h2>Cart Items</h2>
        <ul id="cartItemsList">
        </ul>
    </div>
```

JSON

```
    "basket": {
        "productList": [{
            "product": {
                "id": "111",
                "name": "Dog",
                "shortDescription": "<p>Mans best friend</p>",
                },
                "category": "Canine",
                "availability": "In Stock",
                "variationType": {
                    "name": "Breed",
                    "value": "Collie"
                }
            },
            "quantity": 1,
            "price": "$53.00"
        }, {
            "product": {
                "id": "112",
                "name": "Dog",
                "shortDescription": "<p>Not so best friend</p>",
                "category": "feline",
                "availability": "Low In Stock",
                "variationType": {
                    "name": "breed",
                    "value": "Maine Coon"
                }
            },
            "quantity": 1,
            "price": "$49.00"
        }, {
            "product": {
                "id": "113",
                "name": "Rabbit",
                "shortDescription": "Likes carrots",
                "category": "cuniculus",
                "availability": "In Stock"
            },
            "quantity": 1,
            "price": "$66.00"
        }]
    }
```

JavaScript

```
    var products = document.getElementById("cartItemsList");
    cartItemsList.innerHTML = "<li>" + product + "</li>";
```

Comment: Can you also add the code you use to get the json from your server? I have a feeling this resource would help you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started

Answer (score 6):

If you are loading this from an external file, you will need Ajax or a similar type of call. To use Ajax, you'll have to add a library called jQuery to your project's HTML file. Then you can call your JSON without referencing it as a javascript variable as you see in the following working code snippet.

```js
/* I put your JSON into an external file, loaded from github */
var url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mspanish/playground/master/jessica.json";

/* this tells the page to wait until jQuery has loaded, so you can use the Ajax call */

$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
      error: function(){
        console.log('JSON FAILED for data');
      },
    success:function(results){
  /* the results is your json, you can reference the elements directly by using it here, without creating any additional variables */
  
      var cartItemsList = document.getElementById("cartItemsList");

      results.basket.productList.forEach(function(element) {
      cartItemsList.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend',"<li>" +              element.product.name + " : " + element.price+ " </li>");
      }); // end of forEach
    }  // end of success fn
   }) // end of Ajax call
 }) // end of $(document).ready() function
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>My Cart</h1>
<div id="cart">
    <h2>Cart Items</h2>
    <ul id="cartItemsList">
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @Jessica is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Thanks Stacey -- this helped me.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to parse an object:

```
function logTheObj(obj) {
    var ret = "";
    for (var o in obj) {
        var data = obj[o];
        if (typeof data !== 'object') {
            ret += "<li>" + o + " : " + data + "</li>";
        } else {
            ret += "<li>" + o + " : " + logTheObj(data) + "</li>";
        }
    }
    return "<ul>" + ret + "</ul>";
}
```

If your object is in a string:

```
logTheObj(JSON.parse(jsonString));
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you use an Ajax call or something similar to load external JSON, you need to convert the JSON you've provided into an object that you can reference as a variable. Also, your JSON is not valid. I tried correcting it here, and am going to reference your JSON as an object you can reference via a variable named **obj**. Here is a working code snippet.

```js
var obj = { 
"basket": {
  "productList": [{
   "product": {
    "id": "111",
    "name": "Dog",
    "shortDescription": "<p>Mans best friend</p>",
    "category": "Canine",
    "availability": "In Stock",
    "variationType": {
     "name": "Breed",
     "value": "Collie"
    }
   },
   "quantity": 1,
   "price": "$53.00"
  }, {
   "product": {
    "id": "112",
    "name": "Dog",
    "shortDescription": "<p>Not so best friend</p>",
    "category": "feline",
    "availability": "Low In Stock",
    "variationType": {
     "name": "breed",
     "value": "Maine Coon"
    }
   },
   "quantity": 1,
   "price": "$49.00"
  }, {
   "product": {
    "id": "113",
    "name": "Rabbit",
    "shortDescription": "Likes carrots",
    "category": "cuniculus",
    "availability": "In Stock"
   },
   "quantity": 1,
   "price": "$66.00"
  }]
 }
}

var cartItemsList = document.getElementById("cartItemsList");

obj.basket.productList.forEach(function(element) {
        cartItemsList.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend',"<li>" + element.product.name + " : " + element.price+ " </li>");
});
```

```html
 <h1>My Cart</h1>
    <div id="cart">
        <h2>Cart Items</h2>
        <ul id="cartItemsList">
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: The same comment as on Elad's answer: Where does cartItemsList variable come from? You are also overwriting the innerHTML every iteration instead of adding a new list element every iteration.

Comment: cartItemsList is the element id where the list needs to be created, taken from the HTML snippet posted by Jessica -  var products = document.getElementById("cartItemsList"); You can append to the HTML instead of rewriting, sure. I think Elad was trying to make it the easiest possible, as she mentioned that she needed things simple.

Comment: Yes, it probably is meant to refer to that element. But why isn't `cartItemsList ` defined anywhere? There is even another variable called `products ` that refers to the same element. Why is the same element defined twice in the same piece of code to a different variable? Easy code is good, but it should still behave as expected (add all list items to the list). I'm afraid this answer might end up adding more confusion for Jessica, because it only prints the last element to the list.

Comment: RMo is right, honestly this have left me more confused

Comment: I was focused on fixing her bad JSON, and showing how you reference JSON as variable. I see your point about Elad's code, products is not the right name for that var. So it should be var cartItemsList = document.getElementById("cartItemsList"); @Jessica you need to be more specific about what you are trying to achieve, and try reading up on objects in Javascript if you want to understand how to create and use them.

Comment: @RMo why don't you post your answer to this question?

Comment: @Jessica - do you have no control over these files (are you loading them remotely?) - or is this your own project, where you can edit the JSON? This JSON as you've posted it is not valid, so you need to make changes in order to load it either as JSON or as an object via Javascript. Please describe your project, what you are using to edit your files, and whether the JSON is in a local file, or loaded from someplace else. Then maybe people can help you a little easier.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript version using external json file from previous answer by Stacey Reiman

```js
const products = document.getElementById("cartItemsList");

/* get basket items from JSON */
class Basket {
    async cartItems() {
        try {
            let result = await fetch('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mspanish/playground/master/jessica.json')
            let data = await result.json()
           // return data
            
           /* destructuring data */ 
         let basketItems = data.basket.productList
            basketItems = basketItems.map(item =>{
            const price = item.price
            const{id,name,shortDescription,category,availability} = item.product
            const breed = item.product.variationType
            const quantity = item.quantity
              
            return {price,id,name,shortDescription,category,availability,quantity,breed}
            })
            return basketItems 
            
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)  
        }
    }
}
/* Display stuff from the basket */
class Display {
    displayBasket(basket) {
    //console.log(basket)
         let result = ""
        basket.forEach((item)=>{
        result += `
        <li>
        id : ${item.id}
        name: ${item.name}
        price: ${item.price}
        availability: ${item.availability}
        category : ${item.category}
        quantity : ${item.quantity}
        shortDescription : ${item.shortDescription}
        </li>
        `})
        cartItemsList.innerHTML = result 
    }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ()=>{
    const basket  = new Basket()
    const display = new Display()

    basket.cartItems().then(basket => display.displayBasket(basket))
})
```

```html
 <h1>My Cart</h1>
    <div id="cart">
        <h2>Cart Items</h2>
        <ul id="cartItemsList">
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to convert the `json` from long string to acutely js object.
you doing so by the [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) command. like so:

```
let jsObj = JSON.parse( youreJsonString);
```

Them, you can loop throw youre products in your productList and build your html code, like so:

```
var products = document.getElementById("cartItemsList");

jsObj.basket.productList.forEach( function(product ) {
        cartItemsList.innerHTML = "<li>" + product.name + " : " + product.price+ " </li>";
});
```

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. Is there another way you could explain? I don't understand how I am referencing the json object ...
let jsObj = JSON.parse( youreJsonString);
Also I don't understand what is "longstring"

Comment: Or could you point me in the right direction of what I need to learn in order to understand this?

Comment: Where does `cartItemsList` variable come from? You are also overwriting the innerHTML every iteration instead of adding a new list element every iteration.

Comment: @RMo From the the code in the question. Read the question properly before you dawn vote other people answers.